# JQuery won't write into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to simply output on a loop a line of values into a div. In order to do that I have a loop:

```
 for(var i = 0; i = M1.length-1; i++) { 
   a = b + c; //for example
   $("#matrix").html(a + " ");
 }

 //in the body
 <body>
   <div id="matrix"></div>
 </body>
```

The problem is that it doesn't write anything, just a blank, white page... no content, no values. I tried to declare `var x=1` , `if(x==1){console.log("dsa");$(#matrix).html("hello");`}
The condition was triggered but hello wasn't written there. Any ideas?

As I told you, no drama in my code, I've commented utterly everything in it. The if statement triggers, that's why I put it in here, so surely the compiler must have read the Jq line.

Comment: It may help if you show the code that defines `b`, `c` and `M1`.

Comment: yes, I was just answering Praveen Kumar on the bottom of the page, he proposed exactly the same and it worked. I don't know, i used jq with doc ready in the past as well but I however thought the doc ready part can be omitted... Thanks a lot TO ALL OF YOU and sorry for the time I've consumed you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to do it in the `<head>`, but it looks like you don't have the elements initialized in the `<head>`. So you need to put those functions, after the `document` is in its `ready` state. You need to use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Do whatever here.
});
```

So in your code, do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  for(var i = 0; i = M1.length-1; i++) { 
    a = b + c; //for example
    $("#matrix").html(a + " ");
  }
});
```

Wrapping everything inside `document`'s `ready` event will give your jQuery code access to all the elements in the DOM.

Comment: With (document).ready works. Thanks a lot. But isn't it possible to avoid this, I mean, to avoid separating the jq from the loops. I'll probably find a way to write this this way, though...

Comment: @KDX2 Everything works only after using it. If you don't wanna use it, just move your `<script>` tag just before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: What exactly do you wanna separate? Can you ask that clearly?

Comment: Thank you a lot, once more. I've finally made my program work. Thank you, once again.

Answer (score 2):

You had missing quotes around the selector, and now you have a problem with your for statement, where the condition `i=M1.length-1` is never true, next you'll have a problem because `.html` will replace the entire contents, where you want `.append` instead, like this:

```js
var b=1;
var c=2;
for(var i = 0; i<10;i++){ 
  a = b + c; //for example
  $('#matrix').append(a + " ");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="matrix"></div>
```

Comment: @KDX2 Huh? It clearly shows `3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3` for me.  Are you using an old version of IE?  I can change the jquery version to one that is more compatible with old, broken, and should be shot browsers if so.

Comment: Nope, I mean, your example works well (here) but when I apply exactly the same scheme in my project it remains a blank white page.

Comment: Then the problem isn't with the code you've supplied.  Is `b` defined? Is `c` defined? Is `M1` actually an array?  Are you running the code? Are you running it AFTER the page has been rendered? Did you include jQuery?  Did you include jQuery before your code?  Do you get any warnings or errors in the console?

Comment: no errors found, console log is clear. There are three arrays actually but I highly doubt the problem to come from them because as I said, I commented everything absolutely everything except the jQ line with the even simplified task to render "Hello", not any special letters, symbols or values. And the page remains blank. jQ included, I've double-checked that and the path as well. Whether before or after the page was rendered, I don't know about this.

Answer (score 2):

Make your jQuery selector within quotes and may be `i<=M1.length-1`.

```
for(var i = 0; i <= M1.length-1; i++) { 
    a = b + c; //for example
    $("#matrix").append(a + " ");
}

 //in the body
 <body>
   <div id="matrix"></div>
 </body>
```

Comment: @KDX2 add a console statement to the loop and display a dummy text. Check and let me know if it gets displayed in your browser console.

Comment: @KDX2 Did you add jQuery?

Comment: Yes, I did add jQ libs. About the dummy text, I tried the following, commented everything on the line of jq selector in the loop and created a dummy text, in exactly the same  way  `$("#matrix").html("hello "); `this time with `hello` instead of `a + " "` but I once again got the white page.

Comment: my browser, actually all three of the G, IE and Mz are last versions, everything is fine and updated. Now I've tried to comment everything except the `$("#matrix").html(a + " ");` and it still did not work. Should be something simple, no errors were found.